# Facebook sharer.php ignores GET parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Sharer.php ignores my GET parameters. I tried to urlencode, encodeURIComponent, and even use URL shortener, but still no use. Also, I tried newer share dialog which didn't help as well. URL is working for twitter and vk.com correctly.

Here is the link I'm trying to get fixed:
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F__SITE__%2Fpages%2Fmusic%3Fshare%3D13_5

Comment: please post a real url for testing

Comment: @luschn https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmtrpl.ru%2Fpages%2Fmusic%3Fshare%3D13_5

Comment: and what exactly does not work? looks good to me.

Comment: It should change og:image according to share parameter, but it doesn't. And when I debug, $_GET is empty.

Comment: Your original values were cached by Facebook. From the Facebook url debugger you can force a rescrape which will cache the most up to date values and show you why these values were set. Looking at the current share and the debugger values everything appears to be as expected. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmtrpl.ru%2Fpages%2Fmusic%3Fshare%3D13_5

Comment: @HeyDarren, no, unfortunately it ignores GET request :(